# Swift error: Value of type 'NSObject - > () 'AnimalListTableViewController' has no member 'tableView'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to get rid of these errors in swift xcode

[image: Value of type 'NSObject -> () -> AnimalListTableViewController' has no member 'tableView' / Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';' / Variable used within its own initial value]

If screenshot is too small, here is the code

```
import UIKit

class AnimalListTableViewController: UITableViewController
{
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()//this is where the error appears, it says  Value of type 'NSObject -> () -> AnimalListTableViewController' has no member 'tableView'
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue,
        sender: AnyObject?)
    {
            if let DetailViewController =
                segue.destinationViewController
                    as? DetailViewController {
            }
    }

    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
    {
        DetailViewController.Animal = animals[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is malformed.

At the line generating the error, you're working within the context of the `AnimalListTableViewController` `class` declaration, not within a function. When reading it left-to-right, it's as if you are trying to declare a constant data member `indexPath` of the `AnimalListTableViewController` class.

It looks like you're trying to do this:

```
class AnimalListTableViewController: UITableViewController
{
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue,
        sender: AnyObject?)
    {
        if let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailViewController, let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            detailViewController.Animal = animals[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
}
```

Cleaned up some other things too:

- don't use the class name (`DetailViewController`) also as the variable name. Changed it to `detailViewController`.
- collapsed the `if let` statements into a single statement. Cleaner; avoids optionals.